# Google play services version automatically changes to 11.8

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services

Recently i upgraded my project to android studio 3

In my build.gradle , i have: `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1"`

So it must use gms 10.2.1 , but in `"@integer/google_play_services_version"` i have following:

```
<integer name="google_play_services_version">11910000</integer>
```

And in the project --> External libraries i can clearly see that it compiles gms version 11.8:

[image]

Why this happens?

Comment: Another library you're using might be using that one as its dependency, and the dependency resolution chooses the newest version when resolving duplicated dependencies. You can do `./gradlew dependencies` to print out a dependency graph.

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `./gradlew dependencies` to check the dependency tree.

You are simply using a library that has a dependency with `11.8.0` and gradle uses the newest version.

Comment: is there any way to force gradle/oneSignal to use 10.2.1?

Comment: You can use the resolutionStrategy to use the 10.2.1 in your app but it doesn't mean that OneSignal can work well with 10.2.1